# PySpark: Construct an array based on the order of customer actions

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I created the following dataset of customers' cart actions. This dataset tells me when a customer adds an item, removes an item, and undo actions. For example, a customer can ITEM_ADD, ITEM_ADD, ITEM_ADD, ITEM_UNDO, ITEM_UNDO, ITEM_UNDO ending up with an empty cart.

| event_id | customer_id | event | event_type | event_ts | item_id | next_event_type |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 246984 | 993922 | {"item_id":1000,"customer_id":993922,"timestamp":5260,"type":"ITEM_ADDED"} | ITEM_ADDED | 5260 | 1000 | ITEM_ADDED |  |
| 246984 | 993922 | {"item_id":1001,"customer_id":993922,"timestamp":5260,"type":"ITEM_ADDED"} | ITEM_ADDED | 5355 | 1001 | ITEM_ADDED |  |
| 246984 | 993922 | {"item_id":1002,"customer_id":993922,"timestamp":5260,"type":"ITEM_ADDED"} | ITEM_ADDED | 5460 | 1002 | ITEM_ADDED |  |
| 246984 | 993922 | {"after_id":0,"before_id":1002,"customer_id":993922,"timestamp":5500,"type":"ITEM_UNDO"} | ITEM_UNDO | 5500 | NULL | ITEM_UNDO |  |
| 246984 | 993922 | {"after_id":0,"before_id":1001,"customer_id":993922,"timestamp":5510,"type":"ITEM_UNDO"} | ITEM_UNDO | 5510 | NULL | ITEM_UNDO |  |
| 246984 | 993922 | {"after_id":0,"before_id":1000,"customer_id":993922,"timestamp":5515,"type":"ITEM_UNDO"} | ITEM_UNDO | 5515 | NULL | ITEM_ADDED |  |
| 246984 | 993922 | {"item_id":2000,"customer_id":993922,"timestamp":6000,"type":"ITEM_ADDED"} | ITEM_ADDED | 6000 | 2000 | ITEM_ADDED |  |
| 246984 | 993922 | {"item_id":2000,"customer_id":993922,"timestamp":6010,"type":"ITEM_REMOVED"} | ITEM_ADDED | 6010 | 2000 | ITEM_REMOVED |  |
| 246984 | 993922 | {"item_id":7777,"customer_id":993922,"timestamp":9999,"type":"ITEM_ADDED"} | ITEM_ADDED | 6700 | 7777 | ITEM_ADDED |  |
| 246984 | 993922 | {"item_id":9999,"customer_id":993922,"timestamp":9999,"type":"ITEM_ADDED"} | ITEM_ADDED | 9999 | 9999 | NULL |  |

The result of my query should give me [7777, 9999]

Here is the spark code I used to create the dataset. I know I can do `F.collect_list(F.col("item_id")).over(w.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, end=0))` but this will not take in consideration remove and undo.

```
w = Window().partitionBy("customer_id").orderBy(F.asc("event_timestamp"))
cumulative_customer_items_purchased_df = (
    spark
    .table('testing')
    .where(
        (F.col("event_type").isin(item_events))
        &
        (F.col("customer_id") == 993922)
    )
    .select(*columns)
    .withColumn(
        "prev_event_type",
        F.lag(F.col("event_type")).over(w)
    )
    .withColumn(
        "next_event_type",
        F.lead(F.col("event_type")).over(w)
    )
)
```

Comment: What happens if we undo the event '{"item_id":2000,"customer_id":993922,"timestamp":6010,"type":"ITEM_REMOVED"}'? In that case how would json in the event column look like?

Comment: the third last `event_type` should've been 'ITEM_REMOVED' based on the `event` field. right?

Comment: what happens if instead of 3 undos there were only 2 undos - which 2 item additions would get undone?

Comment: @qaziqarta `{"after_id": 2000,"before_id":0,"customer_id":993922,"timestamp":6012,"type":"ITEM_UNDO"}`

Comment: @samkart the last 2. For example, ADD, ADD, ADD, UNDO, UNDO -> Will only have the first add.

Comment: @satoshi - if customer undoes the 'ITEM_REMOVED' action, the item should be added back. am i getting it right?

Comment: @samkart correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `event`-column in your input DataFrame is of `struct` type and looks like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (246984,  993922,  "{'item_id':1000,'customer_id':993922,'timestamp':5260,'type':'ITEM_ADDED'}", 5260),
        (246984,  993922,  "{'item_id':1001,'customer_id':993922,'timestamp':5260,'type':'ITEM_ADDED'}", 5355),
        (246984,  993922,  "{'item_id':1002,'customer_id':993922,'timestamp':5260,'type':'ITEM_ADDED'}", 5460),
        (246984,  993922,  "{'after_id':0,'before_id':1002,'customer_id':993922,'timestamp':5500,'type':'ITEM_UNDO'}", 5500),
        (246984,  993922,  "{'after_id':0,'before_id':1001,'customer_id':993922,'timestamp':5510,'type':'ITEM_UNDO'}", 5510),
        (246984,  993922,  "{'after_id':0,'before_id':1000,'customer_id':993922,'timestamp':5515,'type':'ITEM_UNDO'}", 5515),
        (246984,  993922,  "{'item_id':2000,'customer_id':993922,'timestamp':6000,'type':'ITEM_ADDED'}", 6000),
        (246984,  993922,  "{'item_id':2000,'customer_id':993922,'timestamp':6010,'type':'ITEM_REMOVED'}", 6010),
        (246984,  993922,  "{'after_id':2000,'before_id':0,'customer_id':993922,'timestamp':6010,'type':'ITEM_UNDO'}", 6010),
        (246984,  993922,  "{'item_id':7777,'customer_id':993922,'timestamp':9999,'type':'ITEM_ADDED'}", 6700),
        (246984,  993922,  "{'item_id':9999,'customer_id':993922,'timestamp':9999,'type':'ITEM_ADDED'}", 9999),
    ],
    ["event_id", "customer_id", "event", "event_timestamp"]
).select("*", F.json_tuple("event", "item_id", "after_id", "before_id", "type").alias("item_id", "after_id", "before_id", "event_type"))
+--------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+-------+--------+---------+------------+
|event_id|customer_id|               event|event_timestamp|item_id|after_id|before_id|  event_type|
+--------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+-------+--------+---------+------------+
|  246984|     993922|{'item_id':1000,'...|           5260|   1000|    null|     null|  ITEM_ADDED|
|  246984|     993922|{'item_id':1001,'...|           5355|   1001|    null|     null|  ITEM_ADDED|
|  246984|     993922|{'item_id':1002,'...|           5460|   1002|    null|     null|  ITEM_ADDED|
|  246984|     993922|{'after_id':0,'be...|           5500|   null|       0|     1002|   ITEM_UNDO|
|  246984|     993922|{'after_id':0,'be...|           5510|   null|       0|     1001|   ITEM_UNDO|
|  246984|     993922|{'after_id':0,'be...|           5515|   null|       0|     1000|   ITEM_UNDO|
|  246984|     993922|{'item_id':2000,'...|           6000|   2000|    null|     null|  ITEM_ADDED|
|  246984|     993922|{'item_id':2000,'...|           6010|   2000|    null|     null|ITEM_REMOVED|
|  246984|     993922|{'after_id':2000,...|           6010|   null|    2000|        0|   ITEM_UNDO|
|  246984|     993922|{'item_id':7777,'...|           6700|   7777|    null|     null|  ITEM_ADDED|
|  246984|     993922|{'item_id':9999,'...|           9999|   9999|    null|     null|  ITEM_ADDED|
+--------+-----------+--------------------+---------------+-------+--------+---------+------------+
```

Note that I added one more `ITEM_UNDO` event in your sample dataset, to undo the `ITEM_REMOVED` event.

I also assume that either `after_id` or `before_id` is set in the `ITEM_UNDO` events, and that `after_id` is for undoing the `ITEM_REMOVED` events, and `before_id` - `ITEM_ADDED` events.

My approach is to add column `qnt` that maps each item's event type to +1 (for added/undo_removed events) or -1 (removed/undo_added):

```
df2 = (
  df.withColumn(
    "item", 
    F.expr("""
      case 
        when event_type='ITEM_UNDO' and before_id!=0 then (-1 as qnt, before_id as item_id) -- undo add
        when event_type='ITEM_UNDO' and after_id!=0 then (1 as qnt, after_id as item_id) --undo remove
        when event_type='ITEM_ADDED' then (1 as qnt, item_id)
        when event_type='ITEM_REMOVED' then (-1 as qnt, item_id)
      end
    """))
  .select("event_id", "customer_id", "event_timestamp", "item.qnt", "item.item_id")
)
+--------+-----------+---------------+---+-------+
|event_id|customer_id|event_timestamp|qnt|item_id|
+--------+-----------+---------------+---+-------+
|  246984|     993922|           5260|  1|   1000|
|  246984|     993922|           5355|  1|   1001|
|  246984|     993922|           5460|  1|   1002|
|  246984|     993922|           5500| -1|   1002|
|  246984|     993922|           5510| -1|   1001|
|  246984|     993922|           5515| -1|   1000|
|  246984|     993922|           6000|  1|   2000|
|  246984|     993922|           6010| -1|   2000|
|  246984|     993922|           6010|  1|   2000|
|  246984|     993922|           6700|  1|   7777|
|  246984|     993922|           9999|  1|   9999|
+--------+-----------+---------------+---+-------+
```

After we get numeric change for each item in `qnt`, we can sum up the results for each item and filter out those with `sum(qnt)==0`:

```
(
  df2
  .groupBy("customer_id", "item_id")
  .agg(F.sum("qnt").alias("qnt"), F.min("event_timestamp").alias("event_ts"))
  .where("qnt>0")
  .groupBy("customer_id")
  .agg(F.sort_array(F.collect_list(F.struct("event_ts", "item_id"))).alias("items"))
  .withColumn("items", F.col("items.item_id"))
).show()
+-----------+------------------+
|customer_id|             items|
+-----------+------------------+
|     993922|[2000, 7777, 9999]|
+-----------+------------------+
```

Comment: i was stuck on a use case where there are 2 'ITEM_UNDO' actions after the 'ITEM_REMOVE'. as in the user adds the item, removes it, hits undo twice (undo remove and again undo add).

Comment: @qaziqarta how can we keep the order to get [2000, 7777, 9999]?

Comment: @satoshi, you can sort the last query by min event_timestamp, like in the last edit